# Getting an Error when developing an App on node.js in windows machine and deploying on cloud with the backend Oracle DB

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I am developing an App using node.js. Dev environment is on windows OS connecting to Oracle DB Where as QAT environment is on cloud with linux flavor. It works perfectly on dev, when it comes to QAT, it throws the following errors. Would like to if I can bundle the oracledb before I deploy in QAT

[ERR] DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". 
      See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help
[ERR] Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html
[ERR] You must have 64-bit Oracle client libraries in LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or configured with ldconfig.
[ERR] If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from
[ERR] http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

I tried to set the LIB PATH. it didnot help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried npm install once you arrive in QAT? I believe packages that rely on node-gyp usually does some compile and would be dependent on the current OS.

Answer (score 0):

The error message looks pretty clear: you need to install 64-bit Oracle client libraries for Linux.  You would already have these on your dev machine for Windows.

The error URL links show how to do it for the QAT environment.  The easiest will be Instant Client which is linked to in the message.

Technically you could bundle the Linux libraries with the app, but you will somehow need to set the operating system library search path e.g. LD_LIBRARY_PATH before you invoke your app.  You could do this with a wrapper shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/whatever/instantclient_19_3
node myapp.js
```

This can get messy and you also need to be uploading all the Instant Client libraries whenever you deploy.

For Linux, I'd recommend treating Instant Client as part of the base OS and make it a requirement for machines to have.  You can install Instant Client RPMs without needing any clickthrough, see this [Dockerfile](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19/Dockerfile).